# How to reinitilize spinner adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am trying to reinitialize the already set adapter for a spinner in android. I don't wanna create a new adapter object because the material spinner library i am using is having an issue when replacing already set adapter with a new object .

So I have a list that changes over time and once after I set the adapter to the spinner initially , afterwards when the list gets changed (updated , cleared etc) I want to reinitialize the already set adapter (using something like adapter.setList() whatever ) ...

I am new to android . Whats the best way to do this with minimal code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after changing your adapter data (i.e. the  list etc.). Without calling it, nothing will happen. Hope it helps.